# smarty link show two active

Tags: templates, smarty

```
{if $smarty.get.m == 'forum'} class="active"{/if}
```

this shows the home link active (/) and the forum link active (/forum) how can I exclude the home link (/) from being active with the forum link (/forum)? I only want the forum link to be active.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different condition for each link to achieve that. Using the following code it should work:

```
<a href="http://domain.com" {if $smarty.get.m == ''} class="active"{/if}>Home</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/forum" {if $smarty.get.m == 'forum'} class="active"{/if}>Forum</a>
```

It it's not the issue, you should edit your question to add more details and code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should've been more clear. I cannot use '' for home I need to use 'index' for home and when I visit the forum link it also highlights index. Is there any way I can subtract 'index' using smarty syntax with the above example.

Comment: @user3792058 It's still unclear. What's your forum link? If it's `forum` and for home page is `index` I still don't see any problem. You use method as above bot instead of `==''` you should use `=='index'`

Comment: When I visit the forum link in its current state it also makes the index active.

Comment: So the problem is not what you asked about, but your logic. `{if $smarty.get.action eq ""}` has nothing in common with `$smarty.get.m`. You could change it into `{if $smarty.get.action eq "" and $smarty.get.m neq 'forum'}`

Comment: @user3792058 Sorry, I cannot help you then. Comments are not the place where you put your code. It's also still unclear what is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. If I find an answer I'll post back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a smarty var in the forum index file that = 1 and then in your tpl set if smarty var eq 1 then it shows active class?

edit:
How i do this on mine is like so.

first I make a smarty var in my page.
Next I use the following code in my menu links

```
<li class="{if $oss eq 'active_signup'} active {/if}"><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
```